# What date format does Amazon Api Gateway support?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-api-gateway

In Amazon Api Gateway, i have created model is as follow:

```
{
  "start": {
    "type": "string",
    "format": "date-time"
  },
  "end": {
    "type": "string",
    "format": "date-time"
  }
}
```

and i am returning

```
{
   "start": "2015-10-12 10:30:00",
   "end": "2015-10-13 10:30:00"
}
```

but this is throwing error in Android SDK as follow:

```
java.text.ParseException: Failed to parse date "2015-10-12 10:30:00"
```

Comment: Are you using the generated SDK from API Gateway?

Comment: @KaHouIeong yes i am using API Gateway SDK

Comment: @Ironman the is no code actually, that is done by SDK internally

Answer (score 0):

According to the JSON-schema documentation, the date-time format takes a date representation, as defined by
[RFC 3339, section 5.6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339#section-5.6)

An example looks like this:

> 1996-12-19T16:39:57-08:00